# Using SpeechRecognizer with a custom keyboard if com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox is disabled

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, google-speech-api

I have a specific use case where I need the com.google.android.googlequicksearch disabled but when I do that I am no longer able to use the Voice Recognition for my custom keyboard. Is there a way around this, or a way to manually include that dependency within my app but not have the app enabled on the device.

Here is how I tried initializing the SpeechRecognizer. I also added the query tag in the manifest for android.speech.RecognitionService

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        checkPermission();
    }
    //////////
    printListofSupportedLanguages();
    /////////
    editText = findViewById(R.id.text);
    micButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Intent speechRecognizerIntent;
    speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    try {
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this,
                ComponentName.unflattenFromString("android.speech.RecognitionService/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService")));

        Log.d(TAG,"SpeechRecognizer Created");
             speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG,"Exception Rec:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely that there would be a way to have com.google.android.quicksearchbox do speech recognition for your app if it is disabled.
If there is also no other app installed that could handle the SpeechRecognizer requests, then it simply won't work.

However, you could integrate a speech recognition SDK into your app and do the speech recognition that way.
For example, Huawei has the ML Kit ASR SDK, which you can integrate into your app as a dependency and do speech recognition within your app: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/ml-asr-0000001050066212

Keep in mind that the number of languages supported, especially on non-Huawei phones, is limited.
You may also look into SDKs for this purpose provided by other companies.

(Disclaimer: I work at Huawei)